# Fill DataGridView from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, datagridview

I want to fill datagridview from Main table and suntables
![enter image description here][1]

My code :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHARKAWY;Initial Catalog=Booking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456");
conn.Open();

txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

DataSet Booking_ds = new DataSet();
DataSet Trip_ds = new DataSet();
DataSet Fleet_ds = new DataSet();
DataSet Partner_ds = new DataSet();
DataSet Guide_ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter Booking_da;

string Bookingsql = "SELECT dbo.Booking.BookingID, dbo.TripTypes.TripName, dbo.Partners.PartnerName, dbo.Booking.DelegateName, dbo.Fleets.FleetName, dbo.Guides.GuideName, dbo.Booking.AdultNum, dbo.Booking.AdultPrice, dbo.Booking.BookingDate, dbo.Booking.ChildNum, dbo.Booking.ChildPrice, dbo.UserInfo.UserName, dbo.Booking.TripID, dbo.Booking.PartnerID"
                  +"FROM  dbo.Booking INNER JOIN"
                  +"dbo.Partners ON dbo.Booking.PartnerID = dbo.Partners.PartnerID INNER JOIN"
                  +"dbo.TripTypes ON dbo.Booking.TripID = dbo.TripTypes.TripID INNER JOIN"
                  +"dbo.Fleets ON dbo.Booking.FleetID = dbo.Fleets.FleetID INNER JOIN"
                  + "dbo.Guides ON dbo.Booking.GuideName = dbo.Guides.GuideID INNER JOIN"
                  +"dbo.UserInfo ON dbo.Booking.UserName = dbo.UserInfo.UserID BookingDate = '"+txtDate.Text+"'";

Booking_da = new SqlDataAdapter(Bookingsql, conn);
Booking_da.Fill(Booking_ds, "Booking");

DGViewBooking.DataSource = Booking_ds.Tables["Booking"];

conn.Close();
```

I can't find the error

Comment: can you post error thrown? and also try to use Sql paramters to avoid any sql injections.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that in your string concatenation you are not including spaces.

```
dbo.Booking.PartnerID"                   +"FROM  dbo.Booking INNER JOIN"
```

would result in `"dbo.Booking.PartnerIDFROM  dbo.Booking INNER JOIN"`

Notice there is no space before the FROM. In the following I put a space after the D in .PartnerID. You would need to do this wherever you use the "+" to join two strings in your example.

```
dbo.Booking.PartnerID "                   +"FROM  dbo.Booking INNER JOIN"
```

In these situations it is usually a good ideal to output the value of your sql string variable and paste it into a query window.Once you have gotten the SQL running you can transfer the changes back to your code. And definitely SQL parameters are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @PatFromCanada's answer, you also forgot your `WHERE` keyword.
Consider using aliases, it will make your code shorter and easier to debug.

```
string Bookingsql = "SELECT b.BookingID, t.TripName, p.PartnerName, b.DelegateName, 
f.FleetName, g.GuideName, b.AdultNum, b.AdultPrice, b.BookingDate, 
    b.ChildNum, b.ChildPrice, u.UserName, b.TripID, b.PartnerID"
                      + " FROM  Booking b INNER JOIN"
                      + " Partners p ON b.PartnerID = p.PartnerID INNER JOIN"
                      + " TripTypes t ON b.TripID = t.TripID INNER JOIN"
                      + " Fleets f ON b.FleetID = f.FleetID INNER JOIN"
                      + " Guides g ON b.GuideName = g.GuideID INNER JOIN"
                      + " UserInfo u ON b.UserName = u.UserID 
                      + " WHERE BookingDate = '" + txtDate.TEXT+ "'";
```